# 4-manifold: $0$-handle $\cup$ $2$-handles along a framed link in $S^3$ (intersection form = linking matrix = presentation matrix of $H_1(\partial M)$)

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

Let $L$ be a [framed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framed_knot) [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_%28knot_theory%29) in $S^3$, consisting of framed knots $L_1,\ldots,L_m$. Let $A=[a_{ij}]\in\mathbb{Z}^{m\times m}$ be its *linking matrix*, with $a_{ii}=$ framing of $L_i$ and $a_{ij}=$ [linking number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number) of $L_i$ and $L_j$.

Let $M$ be the $4$-manifold, obtained as a [handle decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_decomposition) with one $0$-handle $B^4$ and for every framed knot $L_i\subseteq S^3=\partial B^4$ one $2$-handle $B^2\times B^2$ glued along the frame $S^1\times B^2\approx L_i$.

How can I prove that $A$ = intersection form of $M$ = presentation matrix of $H_1(\partial M)$?

Here the *intersection form* of $M$ is defined as follows: $H_2M$ is supposedly (don't know why) isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^m$ and generated by immersions $f_i:kT^2\hookrightarrow M$ where $kT^2$ is the connected sum of $k$-copies of the $2$-torus $S^1\times S^1$, and then the $ij$-th entry of the intersection form is the intersection number of $f_i(kT^2)$ and $f_j(lT^2)$, i.e. $\sum_{p\in f_i(kT^2)\cap f_j(lT^2)}\varepsilon(p)$ where $\varepsilon(p)=\pm1$, depending on what orientation the surfaces $f_i(kT^2)$ and $f_j(lT^2)$ induce on $M$.

I can't even visualize the situation when $L$ is only one knot with its framing $n$-times twisted, i.e. $M$ is $B^4$ with $B^2\times B^2$ attached along $L\subseteq S^3$. What $3$-manifold is $\partial M$? $S^3$ with $S^1\times B^2$ cut out and $B^2\times S^1$ pasted in with $n$-twisting? Can't visualize that...

Comment: A sketch of the proof for the first equality is given in *4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus*, Gompf, Stipsicz, 1999 AMS GSM 20, page 125, Proposition 4.5.11. The last question: if we cut out the unknot $S^1\times B^2$ = thickened z-axis from $S^3=\mathbb{R}^3\cup\{\infty\}$, we get $B^2\times S^1$, so $1$-surgery with n-framing on $S^3$ is actually gluing two solid tori along their boundary via a n-twist homeomorphism, which by [Watkins](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin//lensspaces.pdf) produces the Lens space $L(1,n)$.

Comment: The second equality is Proposition 5.3.11 and Corollary 5.3.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is the content of Leon's comments above, which give a full answer to this question.

A sketch of the proof for the first equality is given in *4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus*, Gompf, Stipsicz, 1999 AMS GSM 20, page 125, Proposition 4.5.11. The last question: if we cut out the unknot $S^1\times B^2$ = thickened z-axis from $S^3=\mathbb{R}^3\cup\{\infty\}$, we get $B^2\times S^1$, so $1$-surgery with n-framing on $S^3$ is actually gluing two solid tori along their boundary via a n-twist homeomorphism, which by [Watkins](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin//lensspaces.pdf) produces the Lens space $L(1,n)$. The second equality is Proposition 5.3.11 and Corollary 5.3.12.